# HttpGet not returning anything - android

Tags: http, get

I'm trying to setup an HTTP connection using the HttpGet but i'm not getting anything back from the website. The only text on the website is a string reading: "Error: Username not passed". I have looked at other questions/answers regarding this issue, but they go into parsing the JSON format. However, I'm just interested in viewing what i'm getting back in the response. Is this possible? Does the android code only accept a response in the JSON format? If so, doesn't this include a string similar to the one I should be getting back from the website? What am I missing? Here's the code I have:

```
public void onClick(View v) {

    //Create a default HTTPClient to setup retrieve data functionality
    httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

    //Create new HTTP GET with URL to php file
    httpget = new HttpGet("http://satpreet.com/mobile/auth.php");

    try {
        response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
        entity = response.getEntity();

        InputStream instream = entity.getContent();
        resultdata = convertStreamToString(instream);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Hit Exception", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }


    //For viewing the result 
    LinearLayout lView = new LinearLayout(this);
    TextView myText = new TextView(this);
    myText.setText(resultdata);
    lView.addView(myText);
    setContentView(lView);
```

The last part is probably not the best way to debug my code. Can you suggest a better way? I tried using the log.i however when I set up a filter to by Log Tag, nothing is caught.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the required permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

to the AndoridManifest?

Maybe also change this:

```
httpclient.execute(httpget);
```

to:

```
httpclient.execute(httpget, new BasicHttpContext());
```

Also notice that you have to use this code asynchronously. Otherwise you'll get some exceptions while running on a real device.

Comment: Yes, I had already added the required internet permission to the AndroidManifest.xml file. I also made the change as you suggested, however the response I'm getting is still null.

Comment: I tried to step through the code. I put a break point on the following lines:

    httpget = new HttpGet("http://satpreet.com/mobile/auth.php");
    response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
    entity = response.getEntity();
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(). "Hit Exception", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

The breakpoints stop on the first two, but does not break on the third one and breaks on the fourth one meaning it fell into the exception case. This means that the code tries to execute but falls into the exception. Why is this happening?